Autocomplete dropdown for related-field filtering in Django admin
I'd like to have a nice autocomplete dropdown in my Django admin backend for filtering out results in the project model according to the subject attached to a person. this is my models.py:
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Person(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class PersonRole(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Project(models.Model):
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=PersonRole)


For now I managed to get a simple list using SimpleListFilter with the following code in admin.py:
class PISubjectFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

   title = 'PI Subject'
   parameter_name = 'subject'

   def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return Subject.objects.values_list("id", "name").order_by("id")

   def queryset(self, request, queryset):
       count = range(1, 100)
       for x in count:
           if self.value() == str(x):
               return queryset.filter(
               person__personrole__person__subject=x
               ).distinct()
               break

How can I turn this long list into a autocomplete dropdown?
I've almost achieved what I want by specifying a custom template for my form in admin.py with template = "custom_form.html", with something like the below:
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<details data-filter-title="{{ title }}" open>
  <summary>
    {% blocktranslate with filter_title=title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktranslate %}
  </summary>

  <select id='select_subject' onchange="location = this.value;">

  {% for choice in choices %}

  <option value="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{choice.display}}</option>

  {% endfor %}

</select>

</details>
<script>
  $(document).subject').select2();
});
  </script>

This creates indeed the autocomplete dropdown, although at each page reload the choice.selected remains the same, and therefore the selected item is not updated. And anyway, I'm sure there is a less clunky way of doing this.
PS: no, something like
class SubjectFilter(AutocompleteFilter):
    title = 'Subject'
    field_name = 'person__personrole__person__subject'

doesn't work (Project has no field named 'person__personrole__person__subject')

The AutocompleteFilter apparently can only look one level deep: https://github.com/farhan0581/django-admin-autocomplete-filter/blob/pre_release/admin_auto_filters/filters.py#L81-L99

Thank you for checking. Also, I'm also filtering for persons with another characteristic (another field in person) which I here omitted for simplicity, so it'd be great if I could extend AutocompleteFilter anyway, with a deeper lookup (and potentially a .filter() ).

Does Subject has a name or some other field to search on?

Yes; I added it to my question.

You can work with the AutocompleteFilterFactory [GitHub], which "traces" the fields, and then thus will list the Subjects and do the filtering, so:
from admin_auto_filters.filters import AutocompleteFilterFactory

SubjectFilter = AutocompleteFilterFactory(
    'Subject', 'person__personrole__person__subject__name'
)
You can filter for principal investigators if an item is selected with:
class SubjectFilter(
    AutocompleteFilterFactory(
        'Subject', 'person__personrole__person__subject__name'
    )
):
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                person__person_role__contains='Principal investigator'
            )
        return super().queryset(request, queryset)

I get Project has no field named 'subject'. I'm using this filtering in the project model.

@HBMCS: how is PersonRole related to Person? I don't see a ForeignKey/ManyToManyField between PersonRole and Project?

@HBMCS: I think I forgot the __name, can you retry?

Many apologies, I forgot the person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE) in the PersonRole class. I've now added it.

Still Project has no field named 'subject'

@HBMCS: you added __name at the end?

Yes, I did. The problem seems to be the 'Subject' bit. Exception Value: Project has no field named 'subject' Exception Location: /usr/local/py_ptracker/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py, line 683, in get_field

@HBMCS: can you provide the full traceback (perhaps a Gist)?

Here it is: https://gist.github.com/lguariento/3efddcdef03450931125b764d5b82206

@HBMCS: the strange thing is that I get it working, the only thing I had to change (with the models you provided), is using an AutocompleteFilterFactory (factory, not AutocompleteFilter), and person__personrole__person__subject__name as field name, so with __name.

Did you put it in the list_filter: class ProjectAdmin(NumericFilterModelAdmin): list_filter = [SubjectFilter,...] admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)`?

I'm an idiot. I had a left-over SubjectFilter declared down below and it ws using that one. With name I got 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'get_queryset', but without name it work like a charm indeed! Thanks! Now, can I chain more filters (e.g. filter also a person with a specific role, i.e. another field in person)?

@HBMCS, you can probably use 'person__personrole__name' as extra filter, this will then be combined (of course PersonRole needs a name field in that case).

This is the other filter I need to chain: person__personrole__person_role__contains="Principal investigator". I wouldn't know where to put it :) !

@HBMCS: ah, in the get_queryset(..) of the modeladmin, since you can there already filter probably, it will then however only return items with at least such PI, you can use .filter(Q(person=None) | Q(person__personrole=None) | Q(person__person_role__contain='Principal investigator')

I'm not sure I'm understanding. Do you mean to define a get_queryset() property within my ProjectAdmin class? Also, wouldn't this filter all results all the time?

...although I could put something like if request contains 'subject' then also filter by PI.

You rock! Thank you so much. I confirm that it must not have __name otherwise I get that error I reported earlier. Other than that, it all works like a charm.
